# Sublime text 3 still using python 2.7. [ I have uninstalled it and installed python 3.3 ]

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Since, we need python 3.3 to install [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) in sublime text 3. So I have uninstalled python 2.7 which was there in my PC and installed python 3.3. I am not getting any error in python terminal for importing the libraries required to install sublime text package control but when I install it through sublime text (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>), I get the same errors which I was getting with python 2.7.

I want to know how do I make default python version for sublime text as 3.3 instead of 2.7.

PS : I have restarted my sublime text as well as my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime Text comes with its own Python version embedded inside. It is Python 2.7 for Sublime 2 and Python 3.3 for Sublime 3. This Python installation is used to run Sublime plug-ins; you also can access the console via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

On top of that, you *can* optionally install (any) Python version on your PC and use it yourself to run your Python programs. Sublime doesn't need it for anything, but if it's there, then it can help you to run the programs directly from editor with the "build system" feature.

Your Python installation doesn't have anything to do with the version that Sublime Text uses internally and doesn't have to match it.

Comment: It worked with latest version of sublime text 3. Seems I had older version of ST3.

Comment: @Kos @ Abhishek Goel when I add my imports which I have imported using pip3 for python3 of course; but when I try and run the script it gives me an error saying that the module has not been installed and it shows the path below which has python 3 and python2.7 written in it

Comment: This still does cause problems since f-strings don't work in the version of Python that Sublime uses.

Answer (score 0):

:| You can very well use Python 2.7 to install Package control in ST3. I'm doing so. You might have messed up a lot more things than just ST3 by removing Python 2.7. For now, You can create a file called `Python.sublime-build` inside `Packages/Python/` of your ST3 directory and write this -

```
{
    'cmd': ['/usr/bin/python3', '-u', '$file'],
    'file_regex': '^[ ]*File "(…*?)", line ([0-9]*)',
    'selector': 'source.python'
}
```

Should work.